# How to reference workbooks that contain date variables in the name?

Tags: excel, vba

I copy select sheets from multiple files to one master file.

The workbook names contain date variables based on user input.

When I try to reference the source workbook I'm getting a Compile error:

> Expected : list separator or )

The line that is giving me the error

```
Workbooks("Y & M & "CD_1993Source.xlsx").Sheets("Custom").Copy Before:=Workbooks("Master.xls").Sheets(1)
```

I added the extra " and that didn't do the trick.

```vb
Public Sub Run_Process()

Dim Y As String
Dim M As String

Y = "2016"
M = "01"

'Opens the workbooks
Workbooks.Open Filename:="\\(Path)\" & Y & "\" & Y & M & "CD_1993 Source.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open Filename:="\\(Path)\" & Y & "\" & Y & M & "CD_1997 Source.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open Filename:="\\(Path)\" & Y & "\" & Y & M & "CD_2002 Source.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open Filename:="\\(path)\" & Y & "\" & Y & M & "CD_1993 Soource2.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open Filename:="\\(Path)\" & Y & "\" & Y & M & "CD_1997 Soource2.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open Filename:="\\(Path)\" & Y & "\" & Y & M & "CD_2002 Source2.xlsx"

'Adding New Workbook
 Workbooks.Add
'Saving the Workbook
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="\\(Path)\" & Y & "\" & Y & M & "Master.xlsx"

Workbooks(""Y & M & "CD_1993 Source.xlsx").Sheets("Custom").Copy Before:=Workbooks("Master.xlsx").Sheets(1)

End Sub
```

Comment: You have a quotation mark error right after `Workbooks(`. You have 3 quotation marks where there should be either 2 or 4 (or more), depending on what all those things are supposed to mean (if they are variables or simply text).

Comment: You should add the rest of the code to te question...

Comment: change the last line to `Workbooks(Y & M & "CD_1993 Source.xlsx")`

Answer (score 0):

Are `Y` and `M` variables?  I'm assuming Y = Year and M = Months?
Should the file name be `201603CD_1993Source.xlsx`?

It all depends on what the original value of Y and M is.  There's also the problem that Vegard mentioned with the extra quotes.
Try out the code below and take note of the `Format$` command - this will take the number and format it as needed returning a string.

```
Sub test()

    Dim M As Long
    Dim Y As Long

    M = 3
    Y = 2016

    MsgBox Y & M & "CD_1993Source.xlsx" & vbCr & _
           Format$(Y, "0000") & Format$(M, "00") & "CD_1993Source.xlsx"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code like this (using variables for Text-parts and objects):

```
Public Sub Run_Process()

Dim Y As String
Dim M As String
Dim NamePart as String
Dim WB as Workbook
Dim NewWB as Workbook    

Y = "2016"
M = "01"
NamePart = "\\(Path)\" & Y & "\" & Y & M

'Adding New Workbook
 set NewWB = Workbooks.Add

'Opens the workbooks, copies the sheet and closes
set WB = Workbooks.Open Filename:=NamePart & "CD_1993 Source.xlsx"
WB.sheets("custom").copy before:= NewWB.sheets(1)
wb.close false

set WB = Workbooks.Open Filename:=NamePart & "CD_1997 Source.xlsx"
WB.sheets("custom").copy before:= NewWB.sheets(1)
wb.close false

set WB = Workbooks.Open Filename:=NamePart & "CD_2002 Source.xlsx"
WB.sheets("custom").copy before:= NewWB.sheets(1)
wb.close false

set WB = Workbooks.Open Filename:=NamePart & "CD_1993 Soource2.xlsx"
WB.sheets("custom").copy before:= NewWB.sheets(1)
wb.close false

set WB = Workbooks.Open Filename:=NamePart & "CD_1997 Soource2.xlsx"
WB.sheets("custom").copy before:= NewWB.sheets(1)
wb.close false

set WB = Workbooks.Open Filename:=NamePart & "CD_2002 Source2.xlsx"
WB.sheets("custom").copy before:= NewWB.sheets(1)
wb.close false

'Saving the Workbook
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=NamePart & "Master.xlsx"

End Sub
```